# Как достать полну информацию про пользователя в Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

Есть Entity User с полями:

```
private String username;
private String password;
private int age;
private boolean active;
```

Как в Controller я могу достать 'эти даные и передать в Model?

Comment: Использовать интерфейс репозиторий spring.